# Facing problem with android WebView

Tags: android, .net, web-applications, webview

I am developing android app which consist only one WebView to open .net based web application.
In my web application i have login screen and list screen and item display screen. After log in list screen will be displayed with some rows. when click on any row it will display another page with selected data.
I am able to open the web application in android web view with out any problem and able to login into the app successfully. after that i am able to see the list which consists list of rows with data, but when i click on any row i am not getting another page in the web view. But if i open the same web app in android browser i am able to click rows and able to see all pages.

Can any one suggest me how can i add all the browser features to my own web view in android?
any help will be appreciated great.

Thanks & Regards,

Sathish

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I have found answer by analyzing more into my code. 
I had removed

`webview.setUserAgent("MyUserAgent");`

line then i got it worked with out any issues.I am posting this because any others like me  will get an idea where we are going wrong.

Thanks all,

Sathish.

Comment: -vote because you did not submitted code in the question. And now you are saying "I have found answer by analyzing more into my code"

Answer (score -1):

If your web app(.net based) uses hyperlink to open next page when you click on a row, then it should work.

But, I think it uses javascript to open another window. So you need to do

```
 webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
 webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
```

as answered by Ovidiu.

Comment: I have added things according to your suggestions but it is also not working. 
When i click on the row i am getting the below error log in logcat.

    09-19 17:50:17.851: ERROR/Web Console(463): ReferenceError: Can't find variable: __doPostBack at undefined:1
please suggest me to get it work.

Thanks,

Sathish.

Answer (score -2):

You can set whatever settings you want on your `WebView` by getting a reference to [`WebSettings`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebSettings.html). You need to set the following on your `WebView`:

```
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
```

Comment: I have added things according to your suggestions but it is also not working. 
When i click on the row i am getting the below error log in logcat.

    09-19 17:50:17.851: ERROR/Web Console(463): ReferenceError: Can't find variable: __doPostBack at undefined:1
please suggest me to get it work.

Thanks,

Sathish.